# file_put_contents not save entire file

Tags: php, html

The function file_put_contents is working but stops saving the date after it reaches the "&" sign. The php file gets the content from a "textarea" on a user interface. The content that is pass to the php file is C++ code. When the file_put_contents function reaches "&myStopDistance" it stops saving and only saves everything before that.

I deleted the "&myStopDistance" to see if that was the problem and it was. However, when it came across "&myDesired" a few lines after, the same problem happen.

UI PHP file

```
<?php
$file = '/var/www/cgi-bin/cpp_get3.txt';
$content = file_get_contents($file);
?>
<textarea id="cppTextArea" rows="15"><?php echo($content);?></textarea><br/>
<button id="save" onclick="savefiles();">save</button>
```

Script

```
request.open('POST', '../../../../../cgi-bin/save_contents.php', true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
request.send('cpp_content=' + cpp_content);
```

PHP file (Problem)

```
<?php
$cpp_content = $_POST['cpp_content'];
$filename = '../cgi-bin/cpp_get3.cpp';
file_put_contents($filename, $cpp_content);
?>
```

If someone can help me to work around that issue so the whole file can be saved.

Comment: You should url_encode the `cpp_content`

Comment: "_Script_" is rather vague. Is it `javascript`? If so, put that in the question, both as a tag an as a heading for that part inside your question - 

and why is this question tagged `c++`? There's nothing in the question having anything to do with C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
request.send('cpp_content=' + encodeURIComponent(cpp_content));
```

I think you lose data when pass url parameter